# ¿Cómo se cuando se lanza el teclado en ios mediante swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

Estoy haciendo un formulario en un `scroll view` y necesito saber cuando se abre el teclado para poder desplazar la vista y que se vea el formulario por encima del teclado.

¿Cómo puedo saber cuando se lanza el teclado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utilizar las notificaciones del sistema tal que así:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)),
    name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
    object: nil
)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)),
    name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
    object: nil
)
```

Necesitas dos notificaciones. La que te avisa cuando se va a mostrar y la que te avisa cuando se va a ocultar. Después, debes create los métodos para gestionar cada caso, como por ejemplo `keyboardWillShow(_:)`